# Getting unique entries for huge data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 500 million entries and some are duplicated. The server can hold the data frame in memory without a problem, but all attempts to apply the unique() function end with the server freezing.

The data frame has this format:

```
"id_A","id_B_C"
"1068095976599746","137459917707_10151666538852708"
"964549956973805","137459917707_10151666538852708"
"10154089033126355","137459917707_10151666538852708"
"548826058653873","137459917707_10151666538852708"
"1048575401891319","137459917707_10151666538852708"
"10209663598697145","137459917707_10151666538852708" 
"10209718419385277","137459917707_10151666538852708"
```

The entries (each row) don't have a unique ID, so the unification of id_A and id_B_C make for a unique entry ID. I know I could apply the unique function by splitting the data frame based on id_A or id_B_C but the number of unique ids is still around the 100 million for each.

Is there a more optimal way to remove the duplicated entries?

Comment: Do you have a data.frame or matrix?

Comment: You should probably use `data.table` or something other than a data.frame. Also, could you clarify what you meant by "I could apply the unique function by splitting the data frame based on id_A or id_B_C but the number of unique ids is still around the 100 million for each."? You don't mean by *combining* those two columns but by *splitting* the data in some way? Can you please show code to explain what you're talking about?

Comment: Also, from a practical standpoint, I don't see a reason to use R for something better suited for a relational database. Why not just do your preprocessing in SQL or something and then send the results to R? R isn't really for ETL of Big Data.

Comment: If `dfrm[ !duplicated(dfrm), ]` does not succeed then you probably need to invest in either more RAM, or an AWS account, or learning data.table, or learning awk. Just because a large dataset will fit into memory is no insurance that you can do anything useful with it. You have not offered enough information about your hardware resources to offer much further advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ff package allows you to use dataframe without loading them to RAM. I am not sure how this would interact with either the duplicated or unique functions but it may alleviate somewhat your RAM usage.